# Star rating system : Works on only one instance

Tags: html, css

I used a code for a star rating system using few bits from some sources online. The system works fine but I'm facing one issue. If there are more than one star rating instances in a page , when I click on a rating , the previous rating I set resets. It's like the CSS works only for one rating instance at a time. I want to rate multiple items but it lets me rate only one.

Here's the css:

```
.starRating{
  display        : inline-block;
  position       : relative;
  height         : 24px;
  background     : url('../images/stars.png') repeat-x 0 0;
  vertical-align : bottom;
}

.starRating div{
  float    : left;
  position : relative;
  height   : 24px;
}

.starRating input{
  position : relative;
  z-index  : 1;
  width    : 24px;
  height   : 24px;
  margin   : 0;
  padding  : 0;
  opacity  : 0;
}

.starRating label{
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 24px;
}

.starRating span{
  display : none;
}

.starRating       input:checked       + label,
.starRating:hover input:checked:hover + label{
  background : url('../images/stars.png') repeat-x 0 -24px;
}

.starRating:hover input:checked + label{
  background : transparent;
}

.starRating:hover input:hover + label{
  background : url('../images/stars.png') repeat-x 0 -48px;
}
```

And the html :

```
<div class="starRating">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
          <label for="rating1"><span>1</span></label>
        </div>
        <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="rating2"><span>2</span></label>
      </div>
      <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
      <label for="rating3"><span>3</span></label>
    </div>
    <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
    <label for="rating4"><span>4</span></label>
  </div>
  <input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
  <label for="rating5"><span>5</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle but there's nothing to see without the stars image. Is it online somewhere to link to? http://jsfiddle.net/D2gJn/

Comment: This is something that would work best with JS/JQ. Your CSS is too generic to work with multiple instances of this star rating scheme and you would need much more CSS to extend it much further.

Comment: Here's the link to the source:
http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/star-rating-widget/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using that exact code but multiplied then its because you dont change the inputs name="" with each instance. You can only have one radio-button per name selected at the same time.

try somethin like this:

```
<div class="starRating">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
          <label for="rating1"><span>1</span></label>
        </div>
        [...]
</div>

<div class="starRating">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating-two" value="1">
          <label for="rating1"><span>1</span></label>
        </div>
        [...]
</div>
```

Comment: Hi i am having the same issue and just a diff. instance name didn't fix it
`<div class="rating"><input disabled="" checked="" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating-1409659686" value="5"><label for="star5" title="Rating!">5 stars</label><input disabled="" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating-1409659686" value="4"><label for="star4" title="Rating!">4 stars</label><input disabled="" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating-1409659686" value="3"><label for="star3" title="Rating!">3 stars</label>...</div>`